# Node.js 0.8.15 on CentOS 5.8 crashes without error messages

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple application in node.js running on CentOS 5.8.
Unfortunately it crashes silently after about half an hour of run time.
Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried to enable logging? If its already logging, what is in the logs?

Comment: Without any details, I can only suggest you a module, because there is nothing specific details here. You can use [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) module, it captures the stderr and stdout to a file and restarts the application (forever) when it crashes.

Comment: That's the problem, it does not log anything out of the ordinary (what I explicitly console.log()).

Comment: Thanks, Mustafa. I know about forever and I use it. However I was hoping someone with similar experience would chime in. I reckon there is something wrong with node.js on CentOS in particular.

Comment: Is your app's memory usage stable during the half hour, or climbing, unbounded?

Comment: @babbata - FWIW I've got a live node.js application (low traffic) running on CentOS with no problems.

Comment: @Hector - what versions of node and centos are you running?

Comment: CentOS release 6.2 (Final) and node v0.8.12.

Comment: Please, run it with `--verbose` switch on the commandline and post the output of the last relevant lines on the question.

Comment: @rcdmk - Run node with --verbose? I am getting an error "unrecognized flag --verbose". Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I must be tired...